# Photons and the electric charge

Tags: particle-physics, photons, charge, quantum-electrodynamics

How the photon doesn't carry a charge yet there is an electromagnetic interactions with (I mean using)that photon, right?

Modification:

In other-words, how a non-charged particles interact with charged particles?

Comment: *"yet there is an electromagnetic interactions with that photon, right?"* - is the classical electromagnetic field (electrically) charged?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I think it's supposed to be no but logically it is supposed to be yes!

Comment: Photons cantain both the positive and negative charges.

Comment: @Hierarchist How is that? It carry no 'electric' charge. Or didn't I get your point?

Answer (score 1):

The photon does not carry electric charge. Theoretically, in the Standard Model, the photon is charge neutral, which is in agreement with the extremely good experimental bounds on the photon's charge (which you can look up [here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/rpp2020-list-photon.pdf) on the Particle Data Group). Subatomic particles like quarks do carry fractional electric charge (up quark has $+2/3$ and down quark has $-1/3$), but they are confined in particles with integer charge (e.g. protons have charge $+1$, neutrons have $-1$). Other non-Abelian gauge bosons (like the gluon) are charged under the force they mediate, namely, gluons mediate the strong force and carry color charge.

Comment: Thanks, but yet I didn't understand how a charged particles interact with a non charged particles?

Comment: @maha The charge of a particle has to do with how it transforms in the gauge theory (its [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) of the gauge group). Interactions have to do with the terms in the Lagrangian, and particles of different charges (i.e. transforming in different representations) can certainly interact with each other.

Comment: The fact that the photon does not carry an electric charge is related to the fact that it does not interact with itself (both are a consequence of U(1) gauge invariance), but the photon can certainly couple to particles which do carry a gauge charge

Comment: Okay, would you just modify your answer with a little bit more details?